# Portrait vs Landscape Mode

Tags: layout, page-layout, mode

Portrait & Landscape layouts - What is the UX guidelines for making two distinct layouts i.e. where the layouts will be significantly different from each other.

Comment: What does it mean when you say - 'the layouts will be significantly different from each other'?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the **Material Design Guidelines** and how [Responsive Layouts](https://material.io/design/layout/responsive-layout-grid.html#) are approached.

A layout can be divided into columns based on the screen width. Material design splits the layout into 4-column, 8-column, and 12-column grids. The content on your page should be displayed based on these columns. 
**Breakpoints** can be used to determine the number of columns based on your screens width.

A layout can be split into **UI regions**. The UI regions should be organized depending on the breakpoints.
An UI region could be a content area or the side navigation. You can i.e use collapsible UI regions for smaller screen widths, whilst displaying it permanently on a larger screen.

You can also have a look at [Component Behavior](https://material.io/design/layout/component-behavior.html) in the Material Design Guidelines. This chapter describes how components behave between breakpoints and also shows some responsive patterns.

---

**To answer your question:**

If you design your layout responsively then switching the layout mode should be included automatically.

---

If your building web-pages with HTML you could have a look at [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) which could help you out a lot with building responsive layouts.